# Automating manual clicking on web application

Tags: selenium, screen-scraping, ui-automation

We have a web application developed with Java EE. There is a certain structure in the application like: Department -> Project -> modules -> scopes. There are many departments (around 20), many projects under these departments, and there are many modules under these projects and there can be many scopes under each module.

There is a option of "create report" when one navigates till a particular scope.  Now the target is: to save all these reports in PDF form on a local machine in order to refer them in future as application is going to be shut down soon. Of course manual clicking through the hierarchy is just not possible as there are tremendous number of reports that have to be saved.

I am thinking of doing some kind of screen scraping in order to automate this work. As I am new to it, I would like to know what are the frameworks available for that. Also how reliable they are. and is there any other way apart from screen scraping ?

For info: The company who owns this application is our client and we need to save these reports as client wants it that way..

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you an employee of whomever owns this application, or are you just scraping someone's database? If you are an employee, there absolutely has to be an API to access the app, even if it just internal. If you are just scraping someone's database, that is generally frowned upon.

Comment: a big task no matter how you go about it... but really the best thing to do here is just keep that application around somewhere... in a virtual machine or something like that so you can generate those reports as needed.